# Tensorflow Object Detection API - How do I implement Mask R-CNN via this?

Tags: tensorflow, mask, object-detection

I notice in the code for the Tensorflow Object Detection API there are several references to Mask R-CNN however no mention of it in the documentation. Is it possible to train/run Mask R-CNN through this API, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You may not like it, but the answer is (for the moment), is no. The API cannot be used to predict or recover masks

They only use a little part of the Mask R-CNN paper to predict boxes in a certain way, but predicting the instance masks is [not yet implemented](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/538f89c4121803645fe72f41ebfd7069c706d954/research/object_detection/core/box_predictor.py#L320).

Comment: This is correct, at the moment you would have to implement it yourself.  We do plan to release an implementation of a mask-RCNN-style model, however, so do stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can implement Mask with faster_rcnn_inception_v2 there is samples with 1.8.0 tensorflow version